# strong parameters has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to figure out why the setter doesn't work on:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships 
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships, dependent: :destroy

end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :company

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :companies, :through => :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :company do |ff|%>
      <%= ff.label :name %><br>
      <%= ff.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, companies_attributes:[:name])
end
```

it works when I do:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, company:[:name])
end
```

So for me it's not quite clear as the documentation says the setter companies_attributes is ceated when accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies

Answer (score 2):

When using `fields_for` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`  they need to match. see  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies`  but `f.fields_for :company` hence the disconnect.

So try changing your form to include

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :companies do |ff|%>
      <%= ff.label :name %><br>
      <%= ff.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

and your user_params method to be

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, companies_attributes:[:name])
end
```

Which should cause them to be populated under `companies_attributes` and your original  `user_params` method to work.  as the `fields_for`  should generate  `user[companies_attributes[id][name]]` since `user has_many companies`  (do you want to include multiple companies in the list to be created?)

Comment: Well I used the logs :) But still didn't get it...   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p08a+oGeMwhECryeQfDyO3th1lLarapkXKQtKb15nWZnD5kGU6o5zJLdTVlBmKK99dpmI4Pczap188P+Uuvqkw==", "user"=>{"company"=>{"name"=>"fff"}, "name"=>"ffff"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
Unpermitted parameter: company
"user_params {\"name\"=>\"ffff\"}"
Unpermitted parameter: company

Comment: :companies doesn't generate a form field for company.name

Comment: See the other part of my answer about changing the fields for to match association/accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: it is a has_many , so it should generate it for  user[companies_attributes[id][name]]

Comment: also my answer applies to just a `has_many`, since it is for the `has_many :through` check out this answer as it might help more  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983131/rails-4-nested-attributes-and-has-many-through-associaton-in-a-form