# has_many through + check_box_tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models: `ProductType`, `ProductAttribute` and `ProductTypeAttribute`. ProductType and ProductAttribute are objects, and ProductTypeAttribute is a join (using has_many :through).

When a user create or update a `ProductType`, he can choose `ProductAttributes` of `ProductType` by checkboxes. 
my problems:

- Only one record created in the join table (ProductTypeAttribute) without reference how many checkboxes was checked
- In the join table only the "product_type_id" has value, the "product_attribute_id" is NULL

Thanks for help!

my ProductType model:

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :product_type_attributes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_attributes, through: :product_type_attributes 

end
```

my ProductAttribute model:

```
class ProductAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :product_type_attributes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :product_types, through: :product_type_attributes  

end
```

my ProductTypeAttribute model:

```
class ProductTypeAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product_type
belongs_to :product_attribute

end
```

my form:

```
<%= form_for @product_type do |f| %>

<% if @product_type.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@product_type.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this product type from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @product_type.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>  



  <p>
    <%= f.label "product type name" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :type_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label "description" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :type_desc %>
  </p>

<% ProductAttribute.all.each do |attribute| %>
   <label>
      <%= check_box_tag 'attribute_ids[]', attribute.id, @product_type.product_attributes.include?(attribute) %>
      <%= label_tag :attribute_ids, attribute.name %>
   </label>
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my ProductTypesController

```
class ProductTypesController < ApplicationController
def index
        @product_types = ProductType.all
  end


  def show
        @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:id])
  end


    def new
     @product_type = ProductType.new
    end


    def edit
    @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:id])

  end


  def create
        @product_type = ProductType.new(product_type_params)      
        @product_type.product_type_attributes.build
        @product_type.save

        redirect_to @product_type
    end


  def update
    @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:id])

    @product_type.product_type_attributes.build

      if @product_type.update(product_type_params)

        redirect_to @product_type
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
  end


    def destroy
      @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:id])
      @product_type.destroy

      redirect_to product_types_path
end


  def product_type_params
        params.require(:product_type).permit(:type_desc, :type_name, {attribute_ids: []})
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really confusing.

> Only one record created in the join table (ProductTypeAttribute) without reference how many checkboxes was checked

This would be the standard behaviour anyway.

When creating records, Rails will only create single records unless you explicitly use code to cycle through the multiple checkboxes and create records for each.

--

Being honest, I think you've overcomplicated your relationships needlessly.

You could get away with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` on your `product_types` association:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :types, class_name: "Product::Type"
end

#app/models/product/type.rb
class Product::Type < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products, class_name: "Product"
end
```

This will allow you to create as many `types` as you want for each product ([collection check boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)):

```
#app/views/products/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   <%= f.check_box :type_ids, Product::Type.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @product = Product.new product_params
      @product.save
   end

   private

   def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:type_ids)
   end
end
```

*If* you then wanted to add attributes to the `Product::Type` model, you'd be able to use:

```
#app/models/product/attribute.rb
class Product::Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :type, class_name: "Product::Type"
end
```

... doesn't really answer your question, but should clear up most of your infrastructure problems I think.

---

**Pro tip** - if you're using models which are "nested" under another, you should [`superclass`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses) them to their "parent" model:

```
-- models
 -- product.rb
 -- product
  -- type.rb
  -- attribute.rb
  -- type_attribute.rb
```

This will result in the following:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :types, class_name: "Product::Type"
end

#app/models/product/type.rb
class Product::Type < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: I designed my schema by this:

http://www.codingblocks.net/programming/database-schema-for-multiple-types-of-products/

I have read about has_and_belongs_to_many that better if I use has_many :through. I have read lots of about this topic

example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280294/rails-4-form-has-many-through-checkboxes

http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/

I dont understand why create only single record in the join table if the user choose more types of product. I think must have a record each type of product.