# Ruby on Rails Nested Forms - Unpermitted Parameters: users_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-form-for, wicked-gem

When trying to add users to a band using the nested_form gem, I am unable to access the users from the params. After some investigation I noticed that I was getting an unpermitted parameters error in the console. I need to access users_attributes so that I can search for users in my database by display name in the controller. (So the nested_form is to add users who are already in the database, if there is a better way to do this, please let me know)

Here is the error from the rails console:

> Started PATCH "/band_steps/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-29 01:59:03 -0400
>   Processing by BandStepsController#update as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oA16RrnTw9Tn/7n45jSjrg+Q6vO8q+TxrYRHLOKSJYs=", "band"=>{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"display_name"=>"Tyler", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"330"}}}, "commit"=>"Next", "id"=>"videos"}
>     Band Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "bands".* FROM "bands"  WHERE "bands"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 57]]
>   Unpermitted parameters: users_attributes
>      (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>     Band Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "bands"  WHERE (LOWER("bands"."name") = LOWER('asdfsbad') AND "bands"."id" != 57) LIMIT 1
>      (0.2ms)  COMMIT
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/band_steps/music
>   Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

The code for the form partial (_form.html.erb):

```
<%= nested_form_for @band, url: wizard_path do |band_form| %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: {obj: band_form.object} %>
    <%= yield band_form %>
    <%= band_form.submit "Next" %>
<%end%>
```

The code from member.html.erb (the page that calls the partial)

```
<h3> Add members to your band! </h3>
<%= render layout: 'form' do |band_form| %>
    <%= band_form.fields_for :users do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'user_fields', builder:builder %>
    <%end%>
        <p><%= band_form.link_to_add "Add a Member", :users %></p>
    <br>
<%end%>
<%= link_to "skip this step", next_wizard_path %><br>
<%= link_to "Back", previous_wizard_path %>
```

The code from _user_fields.html.erb (partial that renders the user fields)

```
<p>
<%= builder.label :display_name, "Display Name" %>
<%= builder.text_field :display_name %>
<%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove this User" %>
</p>
```

Relevant Band Controller Code: (I'm posting only the methods directly involved to save reading time, I can post all the code as needed)

Create Method:

```
def create
    @band = Band.new(band_params)
    @band_params = band_params
    if @band.save
      session[:band_id] = @band.id
      redirect_to band_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
 end
```

the strong parameters:

def band_params

```
    params.require(:band).permit(:name, :location, :about_me, :profile_picture,
   :full_address, :video_link, user_ids: [], genre_ids: [],
   band_video_attributes: [:video_link, :video_name],
    band_music_attributes: [:name, :embed_html], 
    genre_ids: [], users_attributes: [])
end
```

The Band model:

```
has_many :user_bands, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :user_bands
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
```

The User Model:

```
has_many :user_bands
has_many :bands, through: :user_bands
```

To sum up how the code should work: Band form has fields to type in users' display names, I access the display names in the bands controller.

I have spent quite a bit of time looking through my code to see where I made a mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So a band has many users?  In your `User` model, you will want `belongs_to :bands`.  Also, in `band_params` in your controller, you need to include the user attributes in the permitted parameters where you currently have an empty array (like `users_attributes: [:name, :email, ...]`).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry just noticed that `:user_bands` is a join table.  You can ignore the first part of my comment.  For more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983131/rails-4-nested-attributes-and-has-many-through-associaton-in-a-form - you may need to explicitly define `inverse_of:` in your models for this to work.