# Not sure why the VIEW does't work: Rails 4 nested attributes and has_many :through associaton in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-forms, has-many-through, strong-parameters

I followed this page to build my app:

[Rails 4 nested attributes and has_many :through associaton in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983131/rails-4-nested-attributes-and-has-many-through-associaton-in-a-form)

but it shows NOTHING in my VIEW:

(the weird thing is when i typed "f.fields_for :questionnaire_surveRys do |ff|" instead of the right one, it showed me the ocrrect page.

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

here are my Models:

questionnaire.rb

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questionnaire_surveys
    has_many :surveys, through: :questionnaire_surveys
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questionnaire_surveys
end
```

questionnaire_survey.rb

```
class QuestionnaireSurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :questionnaire
    belongs_to :survey
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey
end
```

survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :questionnaire_surveys
  has_many :questionnaires, through: :questionnaire_surveys

end
```

and this is my questionnaire_controller.rb

```
def new
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new
    @surveys = Survey.all

end

def questionnaire_params
    params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:name, questionnaire_surveys_attributes: [:id, survey_attributes:[:id]])
end
```

this is my _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <div class="field">

     <%= f.fields_for :questionnaire_surveys do |ff| %>
       <%= ff.fields_for :survey do |builder| %>
         <% @surveys.each do |survey| %> 
          <%= builder.check_box :id, {}, survey.id %>
          <%= builder.label survey.name %>
         <% end %>
       <% end %>   
     <% end %>
   </div>

  </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

UPDATED:

```
Started POST "/questionnaires" for ::1 at 2015-07-29 22:45:16 +0800
Processing by QuestionnairesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"k4SkRC08PwAHAo1iERmQCkssdQZYgf+uHwofPdeLbXo0O4/psY3Y7i/krQA01omToQ4VLlt/YQDNkcbpLGp86w==", "questionnaire"=>{"name"=>"what just happened", "questionnaire_surveys_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"survey_attributes"=>{"name"=>""}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Questionnaire"}
Unpermitted parameter: name
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "questionnaires" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "what just happened"], ["created_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.374246"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.374246"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "surveys" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.377439"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.377439"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "questionnaire_surveys" ("questionnaire_id", "survey_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["questionnaire_id", "52"], ["survey_id", "38"], ["created_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.378845"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-29 14:45:16.378845"]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questionnaires/52
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

UPDATE - 2015/7/31

```
Started POST "/questionnaires" for ::1 at 2015-07-31 17:46:50 +0800
Processing by QuestionnairesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t/00prIClAUVdqPFxOnkTaxRPhTdY082PAvHb/VQSO4QQh8LLrNz6z2Qg6fhJv3URnNePN6d0ZjukB67DrFZfw==", "questionnaire"=>{"name"=>"OMG", "questionnaire_surveys_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"survey_attributes"=>{"name"=>""}}}}, "commit"=>"Create Questionnaire"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "questionnaires" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "OMG"], ["created_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.440466"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.440466"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "surveys" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", ""], ["created_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.446176"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.446176"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "questionnaire_surveys" ("questionnaire_id", "survey_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["questionnaire_id", "53"], ["survey_id", "39"], ["created_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.450001"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-31 09:46:50.450001"]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questionnaires/53
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

UPDATE - 2015/8/05

I can't upload pics here, hope this is what you need:

```
<input placeholder="vision" type="text" name="questionnaire[questionnaire_surveys_attributes][0][survey_attributes][name]" id="questionnaire_questionnaire_surveys_attributes_0_survey_attributes_name">
```

UPDATE - 2015/8/11

_form.erb.html

```
 <div class="field">
         <% @surveys.each do |survey| %> 
            <%= check_box_tag "questionnaire[questionnaire_surveys_attributes][][survey_id]", survey.id %>
            <%= label_tag survey.name %>
         <% end %>
</div>
```

questionnaires_controller.rb

```
params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:name, questionnaire_surveys_attributes: [:survey_id])

def new
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new
    @surveys = Survey.all
end
```

UPDATE - 2015/8/17

I misused the `has_many :through` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.
In `has_many:xxx :through` case, there is `xxx_ids`.
In `accepts_nested_attributes_for xxx` case, there is `xxx_attributes`.

I used `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in both `questionnaire.rb`and `questionnaire_survey.rb` , which is a mistake.

The correct way to do what I want is use the `has_many :through` only.
Then my `questionnaire_controller.rb` will have

```
def questionnaire_params
    params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:name, :survey_id=>[])
end
```

in _form view, it should be

```
 <%= check_box_tag "questionnaire[survey_id][]", survey.id %>
```

it's much easier now.

@Rich Peck thanks for all your help.

Comment: Okay thank you for the params! It seems something is being submitted for the nested attributes - `Unpermitted parameter: name`. I would highly recommend you add that to your controller and try again - I'll update my ansewr

Comment: please see UPDATE - 2015/7/31.
And I don't think it can be work, because it submit nothing in the params. Can we try collection_check_boxes instead of text_field. 

`1. <%= builder.text_field :name, placeholder: survey.name %>`
`2. <%= survey.collection_check_boxes :survey_ids, @surveys, :id, :name %>`

neither of codes works.

Comment: It will work and we will make it work.

Comment: I hope so, nothing found in my side, do you have any new suggestions?

Comment: Okay, still says you're submitting the nested attributes which means the form is either hidden or something else is preventing it from loading: `"questionnaire"=>{"name"=>"OMG", "questionnaire_surveys_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"survey_attributes"=>{"name"=>""}}}}`. Can you go onto your form, right-click, select `inspect element` and send me the screenshot? This will show whether the form actually has the elements or not. It should have, considering the parameters are being sent.

Comment: please see update - 20150805

Comment: can we try 
2. `<%= survey.collection_check_boxes :survey_ids, @surveys, :id, :name %>`

Comment: Thanks for the update. So it seems the input *is* being put on the page? You can do #2 if you want (I'd have done it already). When you say you "can't see" the input, are you sure you don't have any CSS obstructing it?

Comment: No, i don't have any CSS. Don't you think the ZERO here is weird?`"questionnaire[questionnaire_surveys_attributes][0][survey_attributes][name]"`

Comment: No, it's a standard principle in computing to start with `0` - from what I can see, your embedded form *is* showing.

Comment: The solution of my friend created the code like: "questionnaire[questionnaire_surveys_attributes][][survey_attributes][na‌​me]" – which has no ZERO in it. And it does work fine.

Comment: Oh nice! So it works now? How did you get the form to show??

Comment: please see the UPDATE - 2015/8/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First things first** - if you're not seeing the form elements appear, it's because you've not got it set up correctly in the backend.

For the longest time, I tried to set this up and was getting very frustrated that the embedded form would not appear. It wasn't until I sorted it out properly that it worked. It's called [graceful degradation](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/graceful-degradation) (I think) - whereby no error will appear, yet functionality will be impaired.

---

Firstly, I think you haven't built your associated objects in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/questionnaire_controller.rb
def new
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new

    # You need to build the associated objects, like this:
    @questionnaire.questionnaire_surveys.build.build_survey

    @surveys = Survey.all

end
```

--

Secondly, there is a better way to show checkboxes for your `@surveys` object:

```
<%= ff.fields_for :survey do |survey| %>
    <%= survey.collection_check_boxes :survey_ids, @surveys, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

You can read up about [`collection_check_boxes` here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_check_boxes)

--

Thirdly, you should definitely [learn haml](http://haml.info/). You could write your entire form like this:

```
= form_for @questionnaire do |f|

    .name
      = f.label :name 
      = f.text_field :name

    .field
      = f.fields_for :questionnaire_surveys do |ff| %>
         = ff.fields_for :survey do |survey| %>
           = survey.collection_check_boxes :survey_ids, @surveys, :id, :name

    .actions
      = f.submit
```

--

Finally, don't use HTML elements as styling.

[`<p>` & `<br>` should only be used as markup](https://annevankesteren.nl/2005/01/difference). If you're using them for styling effect, you'll end up causing problems with browser compatibility etc.

You need to let your CSS do the styling (colouring, size, position), and any on-page elements used as ways to separate the content of your application.

---

Update

Okay, so I've looked at your BitBucket:

1. You need to uncomment `@questionnaire.questionnaire_surveys.build.build_survey` in `app/controllers/questionnaires_controller.rb#20`

If you do that, it should work.

I cannot see any problems with the construct of the models and controllers. Are you sure you've refreshed etc?

I see you're calling `<%= render "form" %>` - try putting the form directly in the `new` view to test if it will work.

Also, have you tried using a simple way to add the extra fields, like this:

```
   <%= f.fields_for :questionnaire_surveys do |ff| %>
       <%= ff.fields_for :survey do |builder| %>
         <% @surveys.each do |survey| %> 
           <%= builder.text_field :name, placeholder: survey.name %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Finally, if you post your posted parameters after form submit, I'll be in a much stronger position to see any of the errors/problems you may have.

--

You can change your params to the following:

```
#app/controllers/questionnaires_controller.rb
...
def questionnaire_params
 params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:name, questionnaire_surveys_attributes: [:id, survey_attributes:[:name]])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, however, it seems not working in my case. The story is that I built the Survey first, then I want to associate surveys with the questionnaire. The way I did which is wrong is because I try build and associate them at the same time, according to my friend.

Comment: You are right about " if you're not seeing the form elements appear, it's because you've not got it set up correctly in the backend." It shows nothing when I called <% @surveys.each do |survey| %> , because there is nothing in the :questionnaire_surveys.

I was thinking it (@questionnaire.questionnaire_surveys.build.build_survey) might be work, but it still showed nothing.

Comment: My friend's suggestion is:

`<div class="field">`
     `<% @surveys.each do |survey| %>`
     `<%= check_box_tag "questionnaire[questionnaire_surveys_attributes][][survey_id]", survey.id %>`
            `<%= label_tag survey.name %>`
          `<% end %>`
  `</div>`

Comment: You shouldn't need any of that if you've built the objects in the controller.

Comment: Can you post a github repo of your code? There might be some other issue in the models!

Comment: I have a bitbucket repo, is it ok?
https://bitbucket.org/tienshunlo/surveysays
Check the questionnaire branch. Thank you.

Comment: Models look okay. As long as you're building the objects, they should work.

Comment: It's still not working.
I just post my posted parameters after form submit, hope it's what you need. Thanks for all your help.